# Factors of the multiplicative group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, matlab, order-theory, mathematical-modeling

**The Problem**

I'm working on a problem assigned in the class Introduction to Abstract Algebra and Number Theory. The question is this:

Consider groups of the form $\left(U_n, *modn\right)$, where $n = 3p$, and $p$ is a prime number. Determine if there is a maximum number of factors of the order of groups of this form.

**What I Tried**

I know that the order of the multiplicative group of integers modulo n is equal to $\phi\left(n\right)$, so the order of these groups is equal to $2*\left(p-1\right)$.

I was having trouble thinking of ways to approach this problem, so I wrote a Matlab code to find the number of factors of $n=3p$ for all primes less than 10,000. I made a scatter plot for the number of factors of the order of $\left(U_n, *modn\right)$ vs $n$. I can't include it here because my reputation is still too low, but it the highest numbers look to be growing, roughly, logarithmically.

**The Question**

Can anyone give me some input for how to determine if a set of data is approaching a limit, and how to model that limit if it is?

Comment: What is $U_n$? Does not seem like a standard notation to me... If you mean the multiplicative group $(\mathbb Z/ 3p\mathbb Z)^\times$, actually $2(p-1)$ can have any number of distinct prime factors.

Comment: It might not be. That is the notation I learned from my teacher; I haven't encountered that group anywhere else in my math education yet. Here a link to a site that explains the group: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_modulo_n

Comment: I don't understand your notation. To clarify, when I write $\left(U_n, *modn\right)$, $U_n$ refers to the set of integers from $Z_n$ whose GCD with n is 1, under the operation of multiplication mod n. I agree that there does not seem to be an upper limit to the number of factors of $2\left(p-1\right)$. However, I am at a loss as to how to prove that that.

Comment: I just mean that your $U_n$ is usually denoted as $\mathbb Z_n^\times$ or $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times$ as far as I know :)

Answer (score 1):

So the core of your question lies in understanding the number of prime divisors of $p-1$. The fact is that the number of prime divisors of $p-1$ does not have a upper bound while $p$ approaches infinity.

To see this, you may use some constructive approach. For instance, Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions say that if $A$ and $t$ are relatively prime integers, there are infinitely many primes $q$ of the form $q = Au + t$ with $u \in \mathbb Z$.

To apply to your case, let $A = (\mbox{a product of a whole bunch of primes})$ and $t = 1$, you see that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p = Au + 1$, or $A|(p-1)$.

Comment: For that to be true, you have to make the assumption that there exist infinitely many primes of the form $q=Au+t$, where $A$ and $t$ are coprime, and $A$ is the product of primes. Can you make that assumption?

Comment: That is guaranteed by Dirichlet's theorem of arithmetic progression: [(link from wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)

Comment: The theorem states that the sequence does not contain only primes, so we know that there are some numbers of the form $q=Au+t$ that are not prime. Can we assume that because there are infinitely many primes of the form $q=Au+t$ there are infinitely many generated where $A$ is the product of primes? What if they primes generated in that way level off and the majority are made when $A$ itself is prime?

Comment: We essentially only need one prime of the form $q = Au + t$. For instance, to generate a prime $p$ such that $p-1$ has 100 distinct prime divisors, we need $A = 2 \times 3 \times \cdot \times p_{100}$, and search for a $p$ of the form $p = Au + 1$.

Comment: This doesn't work. The number of factors of the order of a group is the number of ways the divisors can be combined. A group of order $500$ can be rewritten as a group of order $2*2*5*5*5$. That means there are $12$ factors of the order of this group because there are $12$ different possible combinations of the prime divisors of $500$. The order of every group with order $2(p-1)$ where $p$ is a prime generated by $q=Au+t$ and $A$ is the product of a whole bunch of primes will have the same number of factors if those primes only occur where $u$ is also a prime number.

Comment: That is why you need to define $A$ in the way we described. To make sure we are talking about the same thing, here is an example where $2(p-1)$ contains at least 1000 factors. Take $A = 2\times 3 \times 5 \times 7\times \cdots \times 29 = 6469693230$ be the product of the first 10 primes, and by Dirichlet's theorem there is at least a prime of the form $q = Au + 1$. Indeed $q = 11A + 1 = 71166625531$ is a prime. So $2(q-1) = 2^2\times 3\times 5\times 7 \times 11^2 \times 13 \times \cdots \times 29$ have 2304 factors.